# How can I check if a jQuery loaded PHP file changes and execute function if changed?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to make a dynamic dashboard that refreshes every x seconds to deliver new data from a PHP file. I want this to issue an Alert whenever there is a change in the data delivered, not whenever the data is refreshed. I am using require.js, [watch.js](https://github.com/melanke/Watch.JS/) and jQuery. I can`t get it to issue alert on changes on #tfpromo or the variable refreshId. Is there a way to do this in jQuery, JS or Watch.js?

PHP file:

```
$mainbalance = "foo";
    echo $mainbalance;
```

Index.html:

```
<div id="tfpromo"></div>
<script>
  require(['watch', 'jquery'], function(WatchJS, $) {

    var watch = WatchJS.watch;
    var unwatch = WatchJS.unwatch;
    var callWatchers = WatchJS.callWatchers;
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#tfpromo").load("php/dataload.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function load2(){
          $("#tfpromo").load("php/dataload.php");
        }, 4000);

        watch(refreshId, function(){
          alert("balance changed!");
        });
      });
    });

    </script>
```

Comment: `watch.js` is for detecting changes to JavaScript objects, not DOM elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`watch.js` is for monitoring the value of JavaScript objects. So put the balance amount in an object, and update the object in the `.load()` callback.

```
    var watch = WatchJS.watch;
    var unwatch = WatchJS.unwatch;
    var callWatchers = WatchJS.callWatchers;
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        var balanceObj = {balance: 0};
        $("#tfpromo").load("php/dataload.php", function() {
            balanceObj.balance = $(this).text();
            watch(balanceObj, "balance", function() {
                alert("Balance changed!");
            });
        });
        var refreshId = setInterval(function load2(){
          $("#tfpromo").load("php/dataload.php", function() {
            balanceObj.balance = $(this).text();
          });
        }, 4000);

        watch(refreshId, function(){
          alert("balance changed!");
        });
      });
    });
```